# MVP ADVANTAGES OVER THREE TIER ARCHITECTURE

Tags: c#-3.0, webformsmvp

I have read many articles but i could not get exactly what are the advantages of using MVP can you please tell me why
MVP is better than three tier architecture.

thanks in advance for giving reply

Answer (score 0):

MVP/MVC and 3-Tier (or N-Tier) are not exclusive - they address very different concerns.

MVP is one option for how to architect your user interface.  The N-Tiered data access is one way to architect the "model" portion of MVP (or MVC, Presentaiton Model, MVVM, etc).